# titanium text to speech

Tags: iphone, titanium, text-to-speech

is there a way to use a text to speech functions to read a short message under Titanium? Is there any service that can i integrate for iphone?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly yes you can use do. Following this [link](https://github.com/jeska/eyesfree_dev/tree/11982410b2d6f9dbc8cb2f191a54d07dbe819157/iphone-tts) for your reference. You can use this as you require.

And there is also other way with google api using following way.

http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=**Yourtext**. But it has certain limitation like 100 chars and also you have to look for commercial usage conditions.

This you can load in UIWebView passing your text.